Why does "2" > "12" return True?
I am confused by an explanation on comparing different types. It states:

When comparing a string with a number, JavaScript will convert the string to a number when doing the comparison...When comparing two strings, "2" will be greater than "12", because (alphabetically) 1 is less than 2.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp
Additionally, another source states that "12" < "5"
Is the logic that the furthest left digits are being compared, and everything to their right is being ignored? So it's not actually 2 vs 12 it's just 2 vs 1, and likewise not 12 vs 5 but 1 vs 5?

Your assessment of the logic is correct.

"everything to the right" is not ignore if the most left are equal

Why does "apple" < "banana" return true? Because "a" is less than "b".

Because you are not comparing string with a number, you are comparing string with another string. In this case, js uses lexicographic order (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) to compare. So, "2" (ascii code 50) is greater than any string starts with a char with a code less than 50. "1" char ascii code have 49, so "2" greater then "1". So, no matter if "1" continues with something else like in your case with "2". As a result "2" is always greater than "12". It will be even greater than "12929292928382839289382839"
